# Backend-server for mobile apps

Tags: android, ios, mobile, web, backend

I was wondering how people generally realize backends for either complex data-synchronization ("cloud"-sync, since everyone seems to love that word) or simple user-management when developing mobile apps for iOS an Android. I'm not much of a web-guy, so I'm sorta clueless here.

What's your system of choice? Is everyone just writing custom solutions in Ruby, PHP, Java Servlets... which return JSON via HTTP (HTTPS for confidential information) or is there any standardized framework out there that I've been missing? Especially in combination w/ databases - apparently, you need to store the information somewhere.

Sorry for the very general question - but I'm not really sure where to start refreshing my knowledge here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try [Parse.com](https://parse.com/docs/android_guide) as a backend solution.

Comment: it's worth mentioning that they are closing down: http://blog.parse.com/announcements/moving-on/

Answer (score 2):

If it is simple application I use parse.com. If I need more flexible backend I use Ruby on Rails.

Answer (score 1):

It's so simple to get started with a mobile backend these days that you should really give it a shot.

[Kii Cloud](http://www.kii.com) for example supports data and file synchronization and user management including support for Facebook and Twitter accounts and has a generous free tier with carrier grade scalability and reliability.

Answer (score 0):

From all the research I have done Parse or Kinvey sound like the best choices. I was about to build out my won backend out of pure ignorance but after researching thee tools I am going to go with one of them. Kinvey has a pretty cool estimation tool that demonstrates how much time you will save: http://www.kinvey.com/app-cost-estimator

Hey why reinvent the wheel.

Answer (score 0):

Built.io's Backend https://www.built.io/products/backend/overview is my backend solution of choice, its such a simple and straightforward tool to design and build apps.